# Declaring methods with similar signatures and parameters

Tags: c#, methods, overloading

So basically I was asked to make a code but as the title says I've had trouble adding multiple string methods with the same signature. I have to create a class where information such as customer name, customer code e.g. AB001, address and telephone number will be stored. So in other terms I have to use string. My question is: is there another way to code this or maybe a way to solve the problem?

This is what the code looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace myapp2
{
    internal class Customer
    {
        private string name;
        private string address;
        private string customerCode;
        private string phoneNumber;

        public Customer(string nameofacc)
        {
            name = nameofacc;
        }

        public string getName()
        {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(string nameofacc)
        {
            name = nameofacc;
        }

        public Customer(string code)
        {
            customerCode = code;
        }

        public string getCustomerCode()
        {
            return customerCode;
        }

        public void setCustomerCode(string code)
        {
            customerCode = code;
        }
        public Customer(string customeraddress)
        {
            address = customeraddress;
        }

        public string getAddress()
        {
            return address;
        }

        public void setAddress(string customeraddress)
        {
            address = customeraddress;
        }
        public Customer(string number)
        {
            phoneNumber = number;
        }

        public string getPhoneNumber()
        {
            return phoneNumber;
        }

        public void setPhoneNumber(string number)
        {
            phoneNumber = number;
        }
    }
}
```

These are the errors I am getting:

> Error1: Type 'myapp2.Customer' already defines a member called 'Customer' with the same parameter types
>
> Error2: Type 'myapp2.Customer' already defines a member called
> 'Customer' with the same parameter types
>
> Error3: Type 'myapp2.Customer' already defines a member called
> 'Customer' with the same parameter types

I am not very experienced with using C# so if anyone could help, please do!

Comment: Error1: Type 'myapp2.Customer' already defines a member called 'Customer' with the same parameter types                                        Error2: Type 'myapp2.Customer' already defines a member called 'Customer' with the same parameter types                                     Error3: Type 'myapp2.Customer' already defines a member called 'Customer' with the same parameter types                                        These are the errors I am getting..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`properties`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx):

> A property is a member that provides a flexible mechanism to read, write, or compute the value of a private field.

```
private string address;

public string Address
{
     get { return address; }
     set { address = value; }
}
```

Or [`Auto-Implemented Properties`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx):

```
public string Address { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use 1 constructor and manually defile what paremeter with which name you pass in the constructor with default values:

```
public Customer(string nameofacc = null, string customerAddress = null, string number = null, string code = null)
        {
            name = nameofacc;
            address = customerAddress;
            customerCode = code;
            phoneNumber = number;
        }
```

You can use it in code afterwards like this in any combination of parameters:

```
var customer = new Customer(number: "12345");
var anotherCustomer = new Customer(code: "123", customerAddress:"Stub Address");
```

Also for your get/set methods consider using properties instead of pair of methods: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx

In this case you will be able to create class like this:

```
var customer = new Customer {
      NameOfAcc = "John Doe",
      Phone = "123 456 7890"
};
```